# Dependencies in RHEL 6

Tags: linux, unix, rpm, yum

Which file is used by Kernel to resolve dependecies while installing a package. Is it different in Yum and rpm command ?
We can use reqpquer to list the dependecies but i am not able to understand how these dependencies are dound \ Listed ?

Comment: The kernel does not handle dependency management at all. This is handled by the RPM package manager to which Yum is purely an interface.

Comment: Ok Thanks for that info :) . I am a new b in Linux . So is there a file that rpm package manager use to determine dependencies  ?

Answer (score 0):

RPM package is just an container for compressed files. There are REQUIRENAME file into INFO folder inside the RPM. Looks like all dependencies listed there. It's easy to look inside RPM with "mc".